# Model association in sails

Tags: mysql, sails.js

I use sails version 1.0. After upgrading from 0.12 to 1.0 I got error like

> Error: Trying to create an association on a model that doesn't have a Primary Key.

I've added `primaryKey : 'id'` in models.js. What am I missing? I can't get the solution for this. If anyone know this kindly share your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue migrating today, you need to update sails-hook-orm to the latest version, e.g.:

```
"sails-hook-orm": "^2.1.1",
```